# Can i connect airpods to my iPhone Emulator?

Tags: ios, iphone, emulation, airpods

### Problem:

I would like to set up my airpods pro 2, however as I do not own an iPhone I have no way of doing it.

I do own a mac however, where according to the [documentation](https://arc.net/l/quote/bbayozdb) I should be able to see my airpods show up. This however is not the case.

### Idea

If I create an iPhone emulator on my mac and sign into my iCloud on there, could I connect to my Airpods and set them up?

Essentially does an emulated iPhone have access to bluetooth and could it function for my purpose?

### Problem:

I would like to set up my airpods pro 2, however as I do not own an iPhone I have no way of doing it.

I do own a mac however, where according to the [documentation](https://arc.net/l/quote/bbayozdb) I should be able to see my airpods show up. This however is not the case.

### Idea

If I create an iPhone emulator on my mac and sign into my iCloud on there, could I connect to my Airpods and set them up?

Essentially does an emulated iPhone have access to bluetooth and could it function for my purpose?

Comment: The simulator does not have access to Bluetooth